# C# Razor Html.Raw causing conflict with conditional statements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have narrowed down the problem to a single line.
Razor block for ref:

```cs
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
                 <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        if (col.ColumnName == "PONUm")
                        {
                            <td class="text-center"><b>@Html.Raw(row[col.ColumnName])</b></td>
                        }
                        else if (col.ColumnName == "PromisedByDate")
                        {
                            string htmlStr = @Html.Raw(row[col.ColumnName]).ToString();
                            DateTime pDate = Convert.ToDateTime(htmlStr);

                            if ((pDate - currDate).TotalDays > 90)
                            {<td class="text-center">@Html.Raw(String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", row[col.ColumnName]))</td>}
                            else
                            {<td class="text-center td-danger">@Html.Raw(String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", row[col.ColumnName]))</td>}
                        }
                        else
                        {<td class="text-center">@Html.Raw(row[col.ColumnName])</td>}
                     }
                </tr>
            }
```

The problem line:
`string htmlStr = @Html.Raw(row[col.ColumnName]).ToString();`.
If I have that specific line (right where the Razor-syntax starts) in there, it drops off my final else statement.

My goal in this code block is to convert a stored procedure's returned table cell of html data into a string so that I can convert it into a `DateTime` to find a difference in days, etc.

Comment: Do you need the "@" in `string htmlStr = @Html...`? Since you are already writing c#, why not `string htmlStr = Html...`?

Comment: I cut it out once and tried it the way @Blindy mentioned, but I'm just getting worse errors after that. For now, I have just commented out that whole else if section

Answer (score 1):

Why escape to code when you're already writing code? In fact, why use `Html.Raw` at all, you have your data already:

```
string htmlStr = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
```

Of course this is bad for a myriad of reasons, starting with the use of `ToString` when you already know the data type (ie, use `row.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName)`), converting to string and then back to a date, more `Html.Raw` calls instead of literals, overall HTML quality (`<b>` in 2021 would get you fired in my company), etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Coming back and seeing this post 1.5yrs later is hilarious. This answer is so simple to me now. Thank you for having the patience to answer a dumb question like this!